# Cannot resolve class or package 'h2'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, h2

I develop back-end application for my web app.
In my project (SpringBoot + Maven) I would like to add h2 database.
According to tutorials from web:

1. Added following lines in ***application.properties*** file:

   ```
    server.port = 8088
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.h2.console.path=/h2
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver    //h2 seems to be NOT found
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
   ```
2. Added following dependencies in ***pom.xml*** file:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   ```

***PROBLEM:***

in ***application.properties*** : "Cannot resolve class or package 'h2'"

*full inspection:*  "Checks Spring Boot application .properties configuration files. Highlights unresolved and deprecated configuration keys and invalid values. Works only for Spring Boot 1.2 or higher."

Certainly, my Spring Boot is higher than 1.2 (1.5.8). **I've found similar problem in web, but "reloding dependencies" doesnt work,** so still i dont have a solution :). Please help.

Comment: Do you not require a version in the Maven pom.xml? Such as..
 https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2/1.4.197 - possibly at spring boot level too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the issue is somewhere in your pom file. Please find my pom.xml file which I checked with your `application.properties` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mberazouski.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-hibernate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-hibernate</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot And Hibernate</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Once you spring boot will start, check h2-console:
http://localhost:8088/h2

[image]

Hope this will help.
P.S. If you are not aware I suggest you use http://start.spring.io/ for generating of your projects. There you can pick any component which you plan to use. More about that you can read for example [here](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-h2-in-memory-database).