# Cannot resolve class or Package H2

Tags: maven, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2, spring-jdbc

I use a H2 database for my Spring Application. The thing is, everything works. I can access, store and reconnect to the database. However, I get the warning by my IDE

> Cannot resolve class or Package H2

at this

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

It's a bit confusing since I don't know if and how I have to deal with that. Here was once a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890147/cannot-resolve-class-or-package-h2) but the answer does not help and I don't know if I am allowed to ask this question again or if I should post my question in the existing thread?

Here is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/afile;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=no:)
spring.datasource.password=no:)
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

My POM

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>10</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1-1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--      <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
              <version>5.0.7.RELEASE</version>
          </dependency>-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You're saying that everything works fine but it's just the IDE that gives you the warning. What is the IDE which you are using?

Comment: Intellij Ultimate 2018.2

Comment: Did you try reimporting? E.g. right-click in pom.xml -> Maven -> Reimport ?

Comment: Tried. But as I said obviously the import is working otherwise I couldnt use the database right?

Comment: Yes, I get it. The thing is that sometimes the IDE doesn't see things when it should. Do you run your application within the IDE or do you use e.g. a console for that? You could also try reimporting the whole project. I've copied your pom.xml and application.properties, to my IntelliJ Community 2018.2 and it looks fine - I even have code completion for the part mentioned...

Comment: Thank you very much for testing it. Well then I just live with that and won't have to consider any sideeffects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen this before -- and I'm fairly certain it's because your database driver has the `<scope>runtime</scope>` in your POM. This means that at compile time the driver isn't in the classpath, and I guess the property file inspection is using the compile time classpath.

If you remove the scope from your dependency, the inspection error should go away.

Comment: YES. Somehow a combination of removing that scope and refreshing imports and invalidating cache and deleting the mysql repository folder in folder .m2 managed to fix the problem.

Comment: Posting it to JetBrains' YouTrack in case this is something they can resolve:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-201137